# Очистка Activity Android

Tags: java, android, activity, imageview

У меня есть игра в которой есть несколько activity (Магазин, игровой процесс, меню, регистрация и т.д.).

Как сделать очистку activity? Я перешел, допустим, с регистрации в главное меню; на момент нахождения на экране регистрации тратилось 60 мб ОЗУ устройства, - при переходе на главное меню расход ОЗУ увеличился до 120 мб.

Суть вопроса: как убить предыдущую activity так, чтобы при переходе на следующую с нее не поступало абсолютно ничего (чтобы при вызове activity которую мы убили, она заново создавалась, а не приходила к сохраненному состоянию).

Все рекомендации, - `finish(), finishaffinity(), noHistory="true"` в манифесте, сетать во все ImageView при переходе пустоту , убивать активити через Intent в самом якобы стеке, - не приводят ни к чему.

Память поедают именно картинки (P.S. картинки оптимизированы по максимуму самая большая картинка весит 20 кб самая маленькая 2кб).

Расход памяти  на Java колеблется от 15 до 20 мб. На сам код 6-8 мб.

Comment: Актуальная статья про память https://habr.com/company/yandex/blog/423493/

Comment: Возможно у вас утечка памяти

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать - finishAffinity()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

я использую в основной активити, закрывает все, а до этого были возвраты к старым копиям

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      finishAffinity()
    }
```

Comment: использовалось , не помогает